# How can I specify an alternative name for a query parameter in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy, query-string

I want to create a query param that has an alternative version. For example

`/example?lastName=Smith`

should be equivalent to

`/example?surname=Smith`

This is the code:

```
@GET
@Path("/example")
public Response getExample(@QueryParam(WHAT GOES HERE??) String name) {

}
```

How do I handle both possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this with Jax-rs annotations; you'll have to do the combination yourself. The simplest way to do this is probably within the implemenation of your endpoint:

```
@GET
@Path("/example")
public Response getExample(@QueryParam("lastName") String lastName, 
                           @QueryParam("surname") String surname) {
    String name = (lastName != null) ? lastName : surname;
}
```